# Compile from terminal a Java file that extend a parent from another directory

Tags: java, compilation, terminal, extends

I've tried to compile from terminal a java class that extend a parent class and I've noticed that when both child and parent are in the same directory everything works fine. But what to do when parent and child are into two different directories? 
The compiled file of the parent class is into the directory:

```
project/bin/com/app/Parent.class
```

And the java child is into the directory (be aware that java file is not in the src folder):

```
project/Child.java
```

How to compile, from terminal, "Child.java" into the following directory?

```
project/compiledClasses
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should try with the option -cp or -d. You need to specify both parent class path and path of "Child.java".

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried extending/implementing Parent into Child? You can easily do this by creating interfaces.

[image]
Source:
http://www.javatpoint.com

Your option right now would be to 1) follow the second diagram. Make the **class** implement an interface. You would do this by turning your child class into an interface. The slightly easier way to do this is by 2) Extending the child class to the parent class.

This way you can use all of the methods, variables, etc. from the child class, except you would have to move all of the hard code into the parent class, just implementing the methods and

For the first method, you would do something like this to turn it into an interface:

```
public interface thisUsedToBeAClass{
iMustUseThisMethodInParentClass();
iMustUseThisVariableInParentClass();
}
```

Otherwise, if you don't want to move all of the code into the other class from the interface, just use the first method by extending the two classes.

Best of luck,

```
{Rich}
```

Comment: My parent class right now is an an abstract class. According to your diagram I should turn the parent class into an interface, right? 
But you said to turn the child class into an interface, I'm a bit confused. And how all this would help into compiling from terminal?

Comment: Yeah, but should not be the contrary? The parent an interface and all the childs should implements the parent interface. 
What do you mean with extending the two classes? Because I've already the childs that extends the Parent Abstract Class. In that case, I already did this.

Comment: Oh yes, you are right...My mistake. Yes, Child implements Parent.  But, in general, as I said, the interfaces may be difficult to do. So, I recommend the method of just extending the two classes. That way you don't have to move code around. Now, in terminal, just run the parent class.

Comment: Like I said before: What do you mean with extending the two classes? Because I've already did the childs that extends the Parent Abstract Class.

Comment: Public class child extends parent{  CODE }

Comment: then what happens when you run the parent class from terminal?

Comment: Since that the .class of the parent (already compiled) is into another directory when I try to compile the "Child.java" can't find the reference of the parent class.

Comment: Yes, I did. With the option -d. Anyway, please feel free to try by yourself with foo classes. And of course using the same path Tree that I've posted in the question.